# why is my draw of 3-degree polymonial so weird?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am studying LinearRegression and Polynomial regression with scikit learn. I generated 2-degree polynomial dataset, and trained a 3-degree polynomial model. I hope to overfit in the plot with the original data. But the plot does not look like a 3-degree curve. If I change degree to 1, it would shows a line which is fine. What am I missing here?

```
# over fit
poly_features_3 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False)
X_poly_3 = poly_features_3.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_3 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_3.fit(X_poly_3, y)
y_predict = lin_reg_3.predict(X_poly_3)
plt.scatter(X, y, color='black')
plt.plot(X, y_predict, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The values are not sorted, such that the plot jumps back and forth.

I guess you would want to plot

```
plt.plot(np.sort(X), y_predict[np.argsort(X)], color='red')
```

Comment: Never knew `np.argsort()` existed. Nifty!