# Polynomial regression plot looking weird

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot a fitted polynomial using matplotlib:

my code:

```
x = data['LSTAT'].values.reshape(-1,1).copy()
y = data['MEDV'].values.reshape(-1,1).copy()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

xp = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x)

#xp.sort(axis=0)

model = LinearRegression().fit(xp,y)

y_pred = model.predict(xp)

plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.plot(x, y_pred, color='r')
plt.show()
```

my resulting plot:

[image]

Now, I have tried the fix proposed in these two posts:

1. [wrong polynomial regression plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043348/wrong-polynomial-regression-plot)
2. [why is my draw of 3-degree polymonial so weird?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990386/why-is-my-draw-of-3-degree-polymonial-so-weird)

if I uncomment the `xp.sort(axis=0)`, which is the proposed solution of 1), I get the following plot:

[image]

Which is not correct.

If I try the proposed solution of 2)

```
plt.plot(np.sort(x),y_pred[np.argsort(x)], color='r')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have shapes (506, 1) and (506, 1, 1)
```

I'm not sure what is going on...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the order that matplotlib plots.

I fixed this way, but I'm sure there are easier fixes:

```
#fixing indexes and sorting
x_pd = pd.Series(x.flatten())
y_pred_pd = pd.Series(y_pred.flatten())

x_sorted = x_pd.sort_values()

Y_pred = np.array(y_pred_pd[x_sorted.index])
x_arr = np.array(x_sorted)

#plotting
plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.plot(x,y_pred, color='r', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(x_arr, Y_pred, color='g')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]